# Kernel of the integration map $\int : \ker(d)\subset \Omega^n_c(M^n)\to\mathbb{R}$ .

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, poincare-duality

Let $\Omega^n_c(M^n)$ be the set of all compactly supported $n$ forms on a connected, oriented manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. Then there is the map $\int : \ker(d)\subset \Omega^n_c(M^n)\to\mathbb{R}$. I wish to show $\int_M\omega=0$ for any exact form $\omega=d\tau$, say. By stokes' theorem, enough to show that $\int_{\partial M}\tau=0$. I'm not sure why the last integral is zero, any hint will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: When you say manifold (and not manifold with boundary), to me this automatically means $\partial M = \emptyset$. If we're talking about forms with compact support, I infer that we're discussing a non-compact manifold (without boundary). What are you actually discussing? :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand the proof of Poincaré Duality for manifolds of finite type from the book Differential Forms on Algebraic Topology. I found the statement after the proof and in the proof it says that for any oriented manifold $M$, by Stokes' theorem, the integration descends to cohomology.

Comment: Let's say $\tau$ is supported in any open set $U$, so that $\overline U$ is compact and has smooth boundary. Thus you can apply Stokes theorem on this $\overline U, \partial U$

Comment: Can you please be a little more explicit, I guess the problem still remains if $supp(\tau)\cap\partial M\neq \phi$, if $\partial M\neq\phi$.